# TFS 2015 web portal code editor not working on mac - multiple browsers tested

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are experiencing issues in the tfs code editor when opening it in mac, however it works perfectly fine on windows machines.

The portal is working fine, but as we click on the code tab and select a file, the code doesn't display in the editor. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: What browser isn't it working in? Have you tried other browsers? Do you mean "Visual Studio Team Services", or are you referring to an on-premise install of TFS 2015?

Comment: We have tried in Safari, Chrome and firefox.
It is an on premise installation, so using the local IP to access it.

Works perfectly fine on windows machines in all browsers

Comment: Did you try to use the FQDN of the TFS server?

Comment: Doesnt work with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested with Mac OS 10.11.4 + Safari 9.1 + TFS 2015 Update2, the code can display in the editor without issue.

You may compare your environment with mine.

Comment: I think we don't have update 2 installed, probably that will resolve the issue.